# Ошибки при коммите файла на SVN

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

на сервере стоит Visual SVN Server и Manager к нему, на клиенте Tortoise SVN 1.9.7.
Есть много проектов, всё отлично фиксируется и обновляется, но с одним файлом проблемы. Он фиксируется в 10% случаев, причём ошибки при этом выдает самые разные:

> Ошибка: PUT request on
> Ошибка: '/svn/Projects/!svn/txr/91-54/MyProject/bin/MyProject.exe' failed
>
> Ошибка: Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad Request' on
> Ошибка:  '/svn/Projects/!svn/txr/91-55/MyProject/bin/MyProject.exe'
>
> Ошибка: Checksum mismatch for '/MyProject/bin/MyProject.exe':
> Ошибка:    expected:  54f430ca4af5fc2d0c5bcff0d878fb32
> Ошибка:      actual:  e1060a63acecc8db7e6041127eed0fcf  "
>
> Ошибка: Invalid diff stream: insn 0 has length zero  "

Пробовал его удалять и заново добавлять - эффект тот же.
На сервере антивируса нету.